# Python how to get the base instance of an instance?

Tags: python, python-2.6

In C# I would go:

```
myObj.base
```

I have a Date class which inherits from date.datetime. The Date class overrides `__gt__()` and `__lt__()` so when using the `<` and `>` operators they are called. I do not want to use these overrides - I want to use the date.datetime methods on an instance of Date.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you actually mean by "base instance", since not everybody speaks C#.

Comment: Is `.base` the class from which `myObj` inherits from? Or the class name of `myObj`?

Comment: I want the instance not the name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `super()` to get the superclass object. Type `help(super)` in the Python command prompt.

From the manual:

```
class super(object)
 |  super(type) -> unbound super object
 |  super(type, obj) -> bound super object; requires isinstance(obj, type)
 |  super(type, type2) -> bound super object; requires issubclass(type2, type)
 |  Typical use to call a cooperative superclass method:
 |  class C(B):
 |      def meth(self, arg):
 |          super(C, self).meth(arg)
```

Let class B be a subclass of class A and class A have a method `def f(self):`:

- In Python 2, you can call a superclass method in class A from derived class B by using `super(B, self).f()`.
- In Python 3, you can use `super().f()` without the `B, self` arguments.

Comment: this looks like what i want but i cannot tell from the help what i am to supply - is "type" the type i want or the type i am giving - is "obj" the instance i want it from?? how do I get the base instance and call methods on it?

Comment: TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not Date

Comment: I found out by trial and error "type" is the type you are passing. So presumably super will return the the immediate parent. e.g. super(Date, myObj) returns the datetime.date

Comment: @Feanor I added a whole lot more information on this point to my answer (it wouldn't fit here). Please let me know if it helps (or doesn't).

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, this doesn't make sense in Python. There's no "base instance" inside the instance of a subclass.

A Python instance is just one thing, containing a collection of attributes (any of which may have been set/modified by any of its base classes, or indeed from code outside any of its classes at all). Indeed it's possible to *change the class of an instance at runtime*, even transplanting it into an entirely different inheritance heirarchy (this is not frequently a good idea, but it's well-defined). No matter what, the instance remains a single unitary object, which only knows what attributes it has and which class it's an instance of (and in fact that's just an attribute: `__class__`).

**Edit:** If what you want is to be able to invoke overridden methods on an instance, then you do that by using `super`, as hocl answered. However it seems from your comments that you do not fully grok what `super` is doing (which is natural, as it's quite complex).

`super(Date, myObj)` doesn't return "the underlying `datetime.date`" instance, because there's no such thing, only the `myObj` object. Although for your purposes it sounds like this will fill your needs (and you can probably stop at this sentence).

What it does is return is a magical wrapper around `myObj` that looks up methods starting just "behind" `Date`; i.e. it finds the method that would be called if `Date` didn't override it. So in **this** case it will find all methods from `datetime.date`, because you only have single inheritance going on.

A key difference is that this supports multiple inheritance. If someone makes another class that inherits from `Date` and also inherits from `datetime.date` by another path, then `super(Date, instanceOfThatClass)` may not actually hit `datetime.date`'s methods. It depends on the details of that inheritance heirarchy. This is actually the situation `super` was designed for though; it enabled classes in complex multiple inheritance hierarchies to cooperatively call each other's implementations, ensuring that each is called only once, and in an order that is sensible (though it may not be the same order for each ultimate leaf class, so classes in the middle of the hierarchy actually **don't know which super-class implementation they're calling**). My understanding is this complex situation cannot arise in C#, hence it can provide a simple `.base` syntax.

My understanding is also (and this is a bit of a guess), that because C# is statically typed and supports inheriting from classes defined in pre-compiled libraries, that when you have class `Sub` inheriting from class `Base`, inside an instance of `Sub` there really is a complete instance of `Base` which you can get at and then call methods on. This will affect shadowed fields; I would expect (again, as a non-C# programmer guessing a bit) that after getting the `Base` instance from a `Sub` instance, any direct reference to a **field** overridden by `Sub` would hit the field from `Base`, not the one from `Sub`.

In Python, OTOH, there is no base instance, and classes can't override fields. If the constructor and methods of `Date` and `datetime.date` both refer to the same field, it's just the one field in the instance that they're both sharing. So using `super` won't change what field you'll access, as you might expect if you think of it as getting the base instance.

Given that you're not using a complex multiple inheritance situation, if you wanted a simple syntax you could actually call `Date.__lt__(myObj, otherObj)` directly, though it looks ugly  because you don't get to use the infix operator syntax when you do it that way. It's less horrible if you're considering ordinary methods; in that case it's possibly simpler than using `super`.

Take home message: I'm pretty sure `super(Date, myObj)` is what you want in this case. But if you get into more complicated situations, you don't want to think of `super` as the way to get "the base instance", like you would in C#. That understanding will trip you up when in multiple inheritance (which can be bloody confusing anyway), but also when you have multiple layers in the inheritance hierarchy using the same field.

Comment: so there is no way to call the base class method if it is overriden by a derived one?

Comment: understood, thanks for clearing that up! super() does suffice for now as all i need is to call the method on the base class

Comment: Very interesting answer, but I was expecting some comments over __mro__, to understand it's relation with all that

Comment: @artu-hnrq I believe that I decided not to talk about the MRO deliberately (10 years ago!). The full details for the MRO are the *implementation strategy* for the properties I did talk about (like "classes in complex multiple inheritance hierarchies [can] cooperatively call each other's implementations, ensuring that each is called only once, and in an order that is sensible"). You don't *need* to know there is any such thing as an MRO to understand and use `super`. You can of course go deeper and understand the implementation as well, but I was not going there in this particular answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ben! I totally agree with scope judgement. But for those who get until here, I'll reference a [complementary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30354798/2989289) that also takes a look in __mro__