# Python - Demystifying the use of super() to call grandparent method

Tags: python, class, super

I can't seem to fully understand how `super()` really works when it comes to calling methods of a grandparent class. Suppose for instance we have the following code

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing A")
    def method(self):
        print("method A")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing B")
    def method(self):
        print("method B")

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing C")
    def method(self):
        super(B, self).method()

c = C()
c.method()
```

this will output

```
initializing C
method A
```

What I don't get is why the syntax (meaning `super(Parent, self).method()`) is like that, and more importantly what's going on under the hood. The Python official documentation ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)) says

> class super([type[, object-or-type]]) -
> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.
> **The object-or-type determines the method resolution order to be searched**. The search starts from the class right after the type.

Why does the `type` passed to `super([type[, object-or-type]])` have to be the parent class `B` and not the grandparent class `A`? And how does passing `self` (in this case the instance of class `C`) help in determining the method resolution order to be searched?

Comment: You are not overriding anything in your example since all methods have different names. You could just as easily call `self.method_a()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30354798/298607

Comment: @JoshuaNixon right, I fixed the example. Anyways the question was about trying to understand the inner functioning of ```super()```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolution order of `C` is `[C, B, A, object]`. When you use `super`, you are looking for the *next* class that provides the requested method. Inside `C.method`, `super()` and `super(C, self)` would be equivalent: look for the first definition of `method` in a class *after* `C`. When you pass `B` as the first argument, you are asking for the first definition of `method` in a class following `B` instead.

(The second argument, if not `self`, would be used to select an entirely different MRO, rather than just a different starting location for the search within the appropriate MRO.)

Use cases for other arguments to `super` are rare enough that it was worth adding special logic to the language itself to allow `super()` to be used in place explicit arguments. (They aren't just default function arguments, because the "default" values depend on the context in which `super` is called.)

Comment: That's helpful! Thanks